# H4 Tag on <a href> Link

Tags: html, css, w3c, w3c-validation

My website is passed in W3C validation and now I need to put H4 Tag on somewhere hyperlink at homepage. When I put H4 tag some error is showing in W3C exam. so How can I put H4 Tag on  Link.

Here is W3C error code :

```
<li><a rel="http://www.xyz.com/portfolio.html" title="PORTFOLIO"><h4>PORTFOLIO</h4></a></li>
```

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 12):

It's invalid to put a block element (H4) inside an inline element (a). Try putting them the other way around (the link inside the H4).

Comment: Is this still the same for HTML5?

Comment: See Lea Verou's answer. I don't agree with this decision of HTML5, and would still stick to doing it this way.

Comment: I can see some cases where you'd want block elements inside an anchor tag though. Say a div inside an a would be really useful. Or linking a whole bunch of paragraph.

Answer (score 9):

What Karpie said.

Or use (and validate in) HTML5, in which using `<a>` tags as block elements is perfectly valid :)